# Avoid multiple similar lines in python

Tags: python, coding-style

My question is about coding style: When I want to apply a procedure to several variables, like:

```
from pylab import vstack     # the function to apply to many variables
v1 = range(5)      # some dummy variables
v2 = range(9)
...
v20 = range(8)

# now, I want to apply a function to all variables that changes them!
v1 = vstack(v1)   # I really do not need the "old" v1 anymore
v2 = vstack(v2)
...
v20 = vstack(v20)
```

These are 20 lines of almost the same code.
Is there a way to write the conversions ( `vx = vstack(vx)` ) in fewer lines?

Putting them in an iterable does not work:

```
all_v = [v1, v2, v3, .... , v20]
for v in all_v:
    v = vstack(v)

type (v1) # -> v1: <type: list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need them to be in separate variables to begin with? That's usually a code smell. I'd keep them in a list, or a dict if the names are significant, and update that:

```
my_data = {}
my_data['v1'] = range(5)
my_data['v2'] = range(9)
...etc...

my_data = {k: vstack(v) for k, v in my_data.iteritems()}
```

Comment: Your proposition to "bundle" the variables works of course, and I think I'll do this. However, I'd like to know (curiosity) if there is a solution for my problem?

Comment: You can do it by updating the `locals()` dictionary. However, this really isn't recommended. `locals().update({k: v for k, v in locals().items() if k in ['v1', 'v2' ... ]})`

Answer (score 0):

```
from pylab import vstack
parameters = (5, 9, ..., 8)

v = [vstack(range(p)) for p in parameters]
```

This will run a list comprehension on the `parameters` tuple, which contains your parameters to the `range` function. For each parameter in that tuple, the result of the `range` function is passed to the `vstack` function. The results are collected in a list.

So `v[0]` corresponds to the result for the parameter value `parameters[0]` etc.

In your code it didn’t work because you were locally overwriting the `v` variable within the loop. This will not change the item in the original list. If you wanted to create a (new) list from those results, you could use `list.append`:

```
all_v = [v1, v2, v3, .... , v20]
new_v = []
for v in all_v:
    new_v.append(vstack(v))
```

Comment: Thanks! However, for the _practical_ part, I think Daniel's solution is fine. Still, I'm interested (pure curiosity) to know if there is a solution for my original problem.

Comment: @user2055010 Isn’t that answered in the last paragraph & code extract? This is your original tried solution, just working.

Comment: Then, I don't have the new values on the old variable names. (Daniel proposed to update the `locals()` dictionary - that was what I was looking for.)

Comment: @user2055010 You [should never](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) update those values directly. It’s very implementation specific and not guaranteed to work. Change the way you are storing the original values.